# Positive recurrence of a continuous-time jump process, from its jump chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am looking at an irreducible, continuous-time jump process $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ with the following jump times. Let a Poisson process $(T_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ determine the *event times*. With probability $0<p<1/2$, the chain does nothing. Else, with probability $1-p$, it moves somewhere giving a jump time $J_i$. Thus $T_i\leq J_i$ for all $i$.

I know that the jump chain $(X_{J_i})_{i=1}^\infty$ is ergodic, from other parts of my work. How can I conclude that the original chain is ergodic? My intuition is that jumps still occur sufficiently frequently (because with high probability, there are at least $t/2$ events by time $t$).

Thanks for your help,
Derek

Comment: In this case it is particularly easy because the jump time are independent of where you go.  This is so because they are the same exponentials determined by the poisson rate & the coin flip in every state.  The return time to $0$ can be written as $\sum ^N T^*_i$ where N is the return index of the jump chain and the $T^*_i$ are  $poi((1-p)\lambda)$  independent of N.  You probably know how to handle this sort of compound distribution.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Think I've got it!